# error "Webcam.js Error: Webcam is not loaded yet"

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i am setting up a selfie "photobooth". Everything works like fine but i found a bug and dont't find a solution.

I'll explain the function: I have a webcam that shows live-video. If i push the "s"-key it takes a picture and freezes it to the screen for 15 seconds. Wile it is showing the frozen image i can push "s"-key again for stopping the freez and start again with the live-video. Otherwise it jumps back to live-video after 15 seconds. Till here everything works perfect.

Now my problem: If i push the "s"-key more often while the freezed image is showing. It clears the frozen image and shows my background-image giving my a error-box with this message: "Webcam.js Error: Webcam is not loaded yet"

How can this be solved?

Thanks for any help!

Here is my code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Emotionen Fotobooth</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="bg.jpg" id="bg" alt="">

    <div id="foto">
    <div id="my_camera"></div>
    <!-- <input type=button class=anybutton value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()"> -->
    
    <!-- Webcam.min.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webcamjs/webcam.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
    <script language="JavaScript">
       
        let seconds = 15 // time to show image
        
        // Configure a few settings and attach camera
        let propwidth = 1600 // width of webcam window
        Webcam.set({
        width: propwidth,
        height: (propwidth/16)*9,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90
        });
            
        Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
        
        // preload shutter audio clip
        //var shutter = new Audio();
        //shutter.autoplay = true;
        //shutter.src = 'shutter.mp3';
        
        //document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.code == 'KeyS' ) {
        take_snapshot()
        }
        });
        
        function take_snapshot() {
            // play sound effect
            // shutter.play();
        
            // take snapshot and get image data
            Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
                document.getElementById('my_camera').innerHTML = '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
                show_snapshot();
            });
        }

        function show_snapshot(){
            // display results in page
            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
            if (event.code == 'KeyS' ) {
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
                }
            });
            
            var showTimer = setInterval(function(){
                clearInterval(showTimer);
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
            }, seconds*1000);
        }

        //})
        Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
    </script>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am guessing that you have to wait for dom load

Comment: Put the script right before the end of the body tag, not inside the div.

Comment: @code Hi, i tried to change it but i don't get it working. Could you please be more detailed. Thank you!

Comment: Can you update your question with the changes?